# Node doesn't install child module dependencies when version is same as parent module

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Normally I'm able to discover on Google any issues I face, but in this case I have absolutely no idea what to search for.

My parent module has two dependencies:

- `"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7"`
- `"node-snapshot": "~0.3.22"`

However when `node-snapshot` also relies on `~0.2.7`, it isn't installed in `node-snapshot`'s `node_modules` directory. My Snapshot application deploys automatically to Heroku via Travis and therefore has:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "grunt test",
  "start": "node example/server/default.js",
  "postinstall": "node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt build:production"
}
```

Which is also invoked after installing it in my parent module (`npm install node-snapshot`), but fails because both parent and child rely on `grunt-contrib-uglify ~0.2.7`:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "uglify" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

If the parent module relies on a **different** version of `grunt-contrib-uglify` then `node-snapshot` successfully installs `grunt-contrib-uglify` in its `node_modules` directory and everything is tickety-boo.

How would I go about resolving this issue? It's evident to me that all children need their own installations, even when the parent has the same module, because relatively, the sub-module (`node-snapshot`) is unable to find one of its dependencies.

Comment: Even omitting the path doesn't fix it: `grunt build:production`.

Answer (score 2):

After some researching last night, this is apparently a known issue with npm. There are many threads about sub-module dependencies not being installed because the parent module has satisified a particular dependency.

The following thread in particular on GitHub was very informative: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5001

At the moment there is *no solution*, but there **are** workarounds.

In my particular case with the `postinstall` the workaround was to add a `preinstall` with the `--ignore-scripts` flag which prevented the `scripts` hooks from being recursively invoked. This enabled `npm install` to run in isolation and to thus install **all** dependencies irrespective of parent modules.

Therefore my `package.json` now looks almost exactly the same, but with the `preinstall` hook:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "grunt test",
  "start": "node example/server/default.js",
  "preinstall": "npm install --ignore-scripts",
  "postinstall": "bower install; grunt build:production"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

npm doesn't install duplicate modules when it can help it. It also doesn't need paths for run scripts. What happens when you do:

```
"postinstall": "grunt build:production"
```

Comment: It's still the same. I'm instead now trying to remove the `postinstall` and put it into the Travis configuration, but that's not working.